# SVN checkin as different users on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, authentication, tortoisesvn

I would like to have the option to select what user that I'll do my checkin as, when checking in from Windows.

When using TortoiseSVN it seems like the authentication information is stored per repository and it can't be changed.

What would be a good way to make it easily possible to checkin as different users using SVN in Windows?

Answer (score 4):

You can open an explorer window using the credentials of another user, using this:

runas /user:domain\username "explorer /separate"

After that you can check-in authenticating other SVN user.

Comment: +1: Too good. Clearing the cache and/or accessing from command line is pain.

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the stored user id information from the settings page - then it will ask you again. Just remember not to click the "Don't ask again" tickbox when you commit.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

You can delete the authentication data from the Run-Time Configuration Area:  `~/.subversion/auth/` on Unix-like systems or `%APPDATA%/Subversion/auth/` on Windows.  This is all that TortoiseSVN is doing when you click `Settings/Stored Data/Authentication Data.`

Yet another alternative:

You can use the `--no-auth-cache` switch (via the svn.exe command-line client) to specify that you want to be prompted for new credentials on just this one command.

Yet another alternative:

You can edit the `config` file in the Run-Time Configuration area and set the `store-auth-creds` option to `no`. This will prevent the storing of credentials used in any Subversion interactions you perform on the computer.  Therefore, you can manually enter new and different credentials on every operation.

Comment: Yes all those are possible but I would like to store the authentication as well. Just have the option to select which one to use for this check in... 

I had one idea to make a little script that switches the profile (swaps the authentication data in the auth folder) but that seems like a backup solution...